# Should I thin my pine trees branches due to winds?

Tags: pruning, pines, wind-damage

I leave in Greece, and I have these large Pine Trees of Mediterranean type, which have grown pretty good. They were planted by my father from seeds 40 years ago,  now I have a little baby girl, I am very worried about these trees, as the only entrance for my family is below these pine trees.

I don't know if my best option is to cut them down totally or I could save them by pruning on top of them and making their branches bit smaller.

Off course I am very anxious of them as they are that large.
Here are a few pictures of those from side and below:

**Update note:**
A wind gust reached on 2017 at 184 km/h but the wind-speed at 57 km/h.
kind gratitude to this site:
http://marathonas.meteoclub.gr/record.htm

[image: first tree below] , [image: second tree belo] , [image: extend of branch]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are these these Pinus pinea? Are the trees prone to falling down in your area? I would ask a local tree specialist to look at the trees and your soil and their root system. If their roots are stable in your soil, regular pruning of dead branches by a professional would probably be the best thing to do. It seems it would be a shame to cut them down completely if they're not diseased. If they're Pinus pinea, I think they can typically live 50-150 years. But I would ask a tree specialist to look closely at their roots and overall health. Good luck.

Comment: More seems to be Halepensis, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinus_halepensis

Comment: OK, I see that Pinus halepensis trees can live to be 150 years old but sometimes can get too big for a space. Since these are great shade trees, I wouldn't recommend cutting them down unless they are diseased or the root systems seem unstable (typically they are stable because they prefer hot, dry areas and develop large root systems). You may want to look into if they are interfering with your home's plumbing, as that would be another potential concern. Still, though, I would recommend talking to a local tree care professional and take a conservative approach--shade is important.

Comment: Hi Cheryl, thank you for your feedback, indeed I took the decision before I read your answer not to take them down but to prune them. I checked with a pro and the wood cutter ( let's say ) as well that these trees could have a chance. Thank you for your time. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

These pines look healthy.  While big enough to damage structures if they fell, they are unlikely to smash anything flat.  That's what insurance is for.

You may want to prune them so they aren't laying on the roof.  You can also pretty them up by removing dead interior twigs.

Comment: Hi, indeed all votes are going to prune them and that I am going to do. Thanks for your time to give me feedback.